# BrokeredMessage class nowhere to be found

Tags: azure, .net-core

I'm trying to implement a robust message retrying code on Azure ServiceBus Queues like the one detailed on this article: https://medium.com/asos-techblog/reliably-processing-azure-service-bus-topics-with-azure-functions-46ebb7c71b5c. However, I can't find the **BrokeredMessage** class anywhere.

I've added the Azure Messaging ServiceBus package with `dotnet add package Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus --version 7.2.0-beta.2` but the class isn't on `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` namespace. I can't locate it under `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging` namespace either.

Anyone has a clue where this guy might be hidden?

Here's the FunctionApp template for a ServiceBusQueue Trigger function:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyCompany.Azure
{
    public static class ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp2
    {
        [FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp2")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "sbConnection")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` package, you should be using `ServiceBusMessage` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues.

Comment: @DavidG it looks like that this package will be retired.

Comment: @GauravMantri will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm creating a FunctionApp with a trigger on a Queue. I'm trying now to figure out how to implement ServiceBusMessage on that. :-)

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code you have written? Thanks.

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm trying to do pretty much the same it's demonstrated on the article I posted. When I create a Function App on VS  Code activated by a Service Bus Queue Trigger it generates a template with a Run method. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: Please read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#usage. This caught my eye `These parameter types are for Azure Functions version 1.x; for 2.x and higher, use Message instead of BrokeredMessage.`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232048/discussion-between-renato-silva-and-gaurav-mantri).